# UISwipeGestureRecognizer on UIImageview inside UIView detecting wrong swipe?

Tags: uiimageview, direction, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am having problem with detecting swipe on `UIImageView` which is inside self.view.

When I apply `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on `self.view` it works fine, but when i try to apply same on `UIImageview` it detects wrong swipe direction.

**Code:**

```
{

//Swipe Up
swipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUp:)];
swipeUpRecognizer.delegate = self;
swipeUpRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeUpRecognizer;
swipeUpRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeUpRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpRecognizer];
[swipeUpRecognizer release];

//swipe Down
swipeDownRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDown:)];
swipeDownRecognizer.delegate = self;
swipeDownRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeDownRecognizer;
swipeDownRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeDownRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownRecognizer];
[swipeDownRecognizer release];

//swipe Left
swipeLeftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
swipeLeftRecognizer.delegate = self;
swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeLeftRecognizer;
swipeLeftRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
[swipeLeftRecognizer release];

//swipe Right
swipeRightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
swipeRightRecognizer.delegate = self;
swipeRightRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRightRecognizer;
swipeRightRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeRightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
[swipeRightRecognizer release];

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable the user interaction on your `UIImageView`. Use the code below

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```